# Case statement in databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I am trying to run the case statement in databricks

```
salesforce_df = spark.sql("SELECT 
  (CASE WHEN StartDate=date.now() THEN True ELSE False END) 
  as conversion FROM Tablename;")
```

date.now() as to be the current date.
But this synatax is not working. Please advise me .

Regards
Rohit

Comment: What do you mean by syntax is not working

Comment: StartDate=date.now() is not working in azure databricks

Comment: The value has display YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SSSS

Answer (score 0):

To get current date, you can use the inbuilt function `current_date` in Databricks SQL statement to get the desired result.

- The following is the sample data I have taken:

```
%sql

select  *  from t1
```

[image]

- I used the following query to get the desired results:

```
spark.sql("SELECT *,(CASE  WHEN dt=current_date() THEN True ELSE False END) as conversion FROM t1;").show()
```

[image]